# Array_unshift like function that returns the array

Tags: php, arrays

is there a built in function in php that prepends an element to an array, and returns the new array?

instead of returning the new length of the array?

Comment: whats wrong with using array variable that still pass to `array_unshift`?

Comment: Array unshift edits the original array and then returns the size of it. You can later use a `print_r($var_arr)` to get the array.

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog no, `print_r` is not for "getting array", its for printing

Comment: @Anna K. - What's wrong with `array_unshif`? You can copy an array by assigning it to a new variable: `$copy = $array; array_unshift($array);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
array_merge()
```

For example

```
$resultingArray = array_merge(array($newElement), $originalArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Next to `array_merge`, if there ain't any duplicate keys, you can do:

```
$array = array('a' => 'A');
$append = array('b' => 'hello');
$array = $append + $array;
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [b] => hello
    [a] => A
)
```

The plus is the [array union operator<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in which does it, but it's simple enough to wrap it:

```
function my_unshift($array, $var) {
  array_unshift($array, $var);
  return $array;
}
```

This isn't necessary though, because `array_unshift()` operates on an array reference so the original is modified in place. `array_push(), array_pop(), array_shift()` all also operate on a a reference.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
array_unshift($arr, 0);

// No need for return. $arr has been modified    
print_arr($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
)
```